# Send Newline / Carriage return with python

Tags: python

With the Serial Monitor I have the Newline option:

[image]

How can I send the same using python?

I tried:

> 30\r\n
>
> 30\r
>
> 30\n

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 115200)

while True:
    numIn = input("enter delay value: ")
    ser.write(numIn.encode('ascii'))
```

Comment: You tried them and they didnt work? `ser.write((numIn + '\r').encode())`? How are you checking this?

Comment: Thanks, this `(numIn + '\r\n')` works. Typing `\r\n` does not for some reason.